# How can I execute the command “run lime setup” and “run openfl setup” from haxeflixel, on a macbook pro m1 Max, without getting an error?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I recently started the installation process of haxeflixel on my macbook pro, but when I am in the part of running it in the terminal, to see if I managed to install everything correctly, I get an error message about incompatible architecture, and directory error. The architecture of my macbook is m1, and the installation I carried out was done following the steps on the official haxeflixel website, I did not use homebrew.

Error Message:

‘’’[Uncaught exception - load.c(237) : Failed to load library: /usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll (dlopen (/usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll, 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible] architecture (have 'x86 64', need 'arm64')), '/Svstem/Volumes/Preboot/Crvptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll'(no such file), usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll'mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 1×86 641.’’’

I tried to use a pkg on the official website, but they tell me that for architectures like my macbook I need to use homebrew. However, when I try to open lime, or openFl, I get the same architecture error.